# when the window of QFileDialog::getOpenFileName opening, the program has unexpected finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm writing a simple Qt application to test multi-threading (something I am also completely new to).I made a QApplication to manage the GUI,then I write a class VisionApp that contains the class MainWindow which is a subclass of QMainWindow.

In the MainWindow class,I write a function void MainWindow::getfromfilevd() which is connected to the button using this:

```
QObject::connect(ui->FileVdButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(getfromfilevd()));
```

Then I want to read a image from file by using QFileDialog::getOpenFileName,my code is here:

```
void MainWindow::getfromfilevd()
{
    //mutex.lock();
    from_imgorvd = true;

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Image"),"", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp *.xpm)"));
    if(fileName.isEmpty()) {
        cv::Mat image;
        image = cv::imread(fileName.toUtf8().constData(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        mutex.lock();
        Mat_Img = image.clone();
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

however,every time I click the button ,the window of QFileDialog opened but it is blank,then my program finished unexpected.

when I use this code:

```
void MainWindow::getfromfilevd()
{

    from_imgorvd = true;

    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("/home/somnus/Picture/mouse.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if(! image.data) {
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    }
    else {
        mutex.lock();
        Mat_Img = image.clone();
        mutex.unlock();
    }

}
```

It works well.

I am really wonder which mistake I take...
Hope for your help

Comment: good first post!! Are you using QtCreator? Can you launch in debug mode and see where it crash??

Comment: You talk about threads. Are you sure the dialog opening code is running in the main thread? In Qt, all GUI code must run there. Another thing to try: create a simple test program which just opens the dialog in `main()` (remember to create the `QApplication` object first) and prints the returned file name, and see if that works.

Comment: It should be `if(!fileName.isEmpty()) ...`

Comment: oh~thank you .I find the most important bug at last.My cpu is used up by my image processing,the file open dialog left cpu starved ,so the window of the dialog is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this, `!fileName.isEmpty()` in stead of `fileName.isEmpty()` because you need to load image when the file name is not empty not the opposite.